# Do not delete "default" avatar image after uploading new avatar

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Ive got an upload avatar section on my Laravel(5.4) site, and if users haven't uploaded an avatar yet, depending on their gender it will display either a male or female "default" avatar,

that all works fine, and also uploading a new one works fine, but when uploading a new avatar it deletes or overrides the default-avatar

(My UserController)

```
   public function update(Request $r)

{

                $this->validate($r, [
                    'location' => 'required',
                    'about' => 'required|max:355'
                ]);

                Auth::user()->profile()->update([
                'location' => $r->location,
                'about' => $r->about

                ]);
    return back()->with('msg', 'Profile successfully edited');

$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

// Handle the user upload of avatar
if ($r->hasFile('avatar')) {
    $avatar = $r->file('avatar');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
     Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save('uploads/avatars/' . $filename);
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->avatar = $filename;
    $user->save();
}
    // Delete current image before uploading new image
    if ($user->avatar !== 'man.png' || 'woman.png') {
         //$file = public_path('uploads/avatars/' . $user->avatar);
        $file = 'uploads/avatars/' . $user->avatar;
        //$destinationPath = 'uploads/' . $id . '/';
    }

        if (File::exists($file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }


    return back()->with('msg', 'Profile successfully edited');



        }




    }
```

in my RegisterController I have

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    if($data['gender']){

        $avatar = 'man.png'; 
    }

    else{

       $avatar = 'woman.png'; 
    }
```

in my (profile) edit.blade.php

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('profile.update') }}" 
 method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group">

                                    <label for="avatar" >Change Avatar</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="avatar" class="form-control" accept="image/*">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="_token"   value="{{ csrf_token() }}">


                           </div>
```

I would like to keep both male and female.png files to be left untouched, can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your if statement isn't working is because `'woman.png'` will evaluate to `true` so your if statement is essentially:

```
if ($user->avatar !== 'man.png' || true)
```

which will always be `true`.

Change your if statement to be:

```
if ($user->avatar !== 'man.png' && $user->avatar !== 'woman.png')

    $file = public_path('uploads/avatars/' . $user->avatar);

    if (File::exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems like a really good solution,  I've implemented it, but now it just keeps the default image( I. e not uploading a new image)...

Comment: @AtomisedClarity Do you still have the original logic for saving the new image or have you removed that?

Comment: @AtomisedClarity Oh...the bit of code I included in to my answer was just to replace the if statement that checks to see if another image should be deleted...

Comment: right, silly me, 
thanks mate it worked out great!

(see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I got it to work like

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

// Handle the user upload of avatar
if ($r->hasFile('avatar')) {
    $avatar = $r->file('avatar');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

}



    // Delete current image before uploading new image

if ($user->avatar !== 'man.png' && $user->avatar !== 'woman.png')

        $file = 'uploads/avatars/' . $user->avatar;

if (File::exists($file)) {
    unlink($file);
}

    Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save('uploads/avatars/' . 
    $filename);
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->avatar = $filename;
    $user->save();        
    return back()->with('msg', 'Profiel is bijgewerkt');



               }




     }
```